# error while executing the command assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, handlebars.js, rake, assets

Trying to do **RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile**

Get this error message:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 48027, col: 50, pos: 1986183)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:2357:10748)
    at js_error (<eval>:2357:10967)
    at croak (<eval>:2357:19192)
    at token_error (<eval>:2357:19329)
    at unexpected (<eval>:2357:19417)
    at expr_atom (<eval>:2357:27609)
    at maybe_unary (<eval>:2357:30102)
    at expr_ops (<eval>:2357:30860)
    at maybe_conditional (<eval>:2357:30952)
    at maybe_assign (<eval>:2357:31395)
    at maybe_assign (<eval>:2357:31569)
    at expression (<eval>:2357:31708)
    at expr_list (<eval>:2357:27913)
    at subscripts (<eval>:2357:29811)
  (in /home/parts-soft/www/parts-soft/releases/20171122232617/apps/www/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2357:10748)
js_error ((execjs):2357:10967)
croak ((execjs):2357:19192)
token_error ((execjs):2357:19329)
unexpected ((execjs):2357:19417)
expr_atom ((execjs):2357:27609)
maybe_unary ((execjs):2357:30102)
expr_ops ((execjs):2357:30860)
maybe_conditional ((execjs):2357:30952)
maybe_assign ((execjs):2357:31395)
maybe_assign ((execjs):2357:31569)
expression ((execjs):2357:31708)
expr_list ((execjs):2357:27913)
subscripts ((execjs):2357:29811)
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:36:in `rescue in block in eval'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:33:in `block in eval'
/home/parts-soft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@parts-script-new-admin/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
```

When I do **RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all**

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'handlebars.runtime'
  (in /home/oil/www/oil/releases/20171122232617/apps/www/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:32)
```

Tell me what can I do?
In app.js I have not changed anything

Answer (score 0):

Compile all assets locally.

Try following steps:

1. Add below code in `Gemfile`

   `group :assets do
     gem 'sass-rails'
     gem 'coffee-rails'
     gem 'therubyracer'
   end`
2. Run `bundle install`
3. change line in config/environments/production.rb 
     `config.assets.compile = true`
4. Run commands:

   `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`